URI malformed issue from @angular-devkit's dependency library Vite

Just created new angular application (version - 17.3.9) using command ng new url-test-app
then start application using command - npm start
Now I navigate to http://localhost:4200 . It works fine
Then add a new query param with value %_24Q3, for example,
http://localhost:4200/?testParam=test%_24Q3

We will get below issue,
URI malformed  
    at decodeURI (<anonymous>)  
    at viteTransformMiddleware (file:///D:/angular/url-test- app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:63436:19)  
    at call (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:42750:7)  
    at next (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:42694:5)  
    at viteHMRPingMiddleware (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:64700:13)  
    at call (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:42750:7)  
    at next (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:42694:5)  
    at next (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:42672:14)  
    at viteCachedTransformMiddleware (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:63421:9)  
    at call (file:///D:/angular/url-test-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-k5wXcrSr.js:42750:7

I am not able to handle this with Angular error handler

 http://localhost:4200/?testParam=test%_24Q3

That URL is malformed, because % indicates the start of a hex-encoded value, but you got no valid hex digits following that.
You need to properly URL-encode the %, as %25 - so your URL needs to be http://localhost:4200/?testParam=test%25_24Q3. Then calling decodeURI on it will work fine.

thanks for the reply.
Is that possible to handle error from angular application without breaking application behaviour?

I couldn't say, but it would probably require changes to the angular code itself, I suppose. But why would using correctly encoded URLs break your application to begin with?

Thanks for your information, I suggested to client same you suggested
